# How to format date fields in angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I get this data from my web API

[image]

The data is an array of IOferta

```
export interface IOferta {
 id: string
 idPresentada: string;
 descripcion: string;
 fechaPresentacion: Date;
 responsable: string;
 presentada: string;
 plazo: string;
 importe: number;
 organismo: string
}
```

I have this table un my component html

```
<section class="container mat-elevation-z8">
 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay" [sticky]="true">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index">
      <div *ngIf="column=='fechaPresentacion'">
        {{element[column] | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="column=='importe'">
        {{element[column] | currency: 'EUR'}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="column!='fechaPresentacion' && column!='importe'">
        {{element[column]}}
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky:true"></tr>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</mat-table>
```

But I see this

[image]

I don't understand why I don't see the fechePresentacion values

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You not see the dates because they are "strings", not "date object".

I suggest you use map to transform the dates in your service

```
getData(){
  return this.httClient.get(....).pipe(
    map((res:any[])=>{
      res.forEach(x=>x.fechaPresentacion=new Date(x.fechaPresentacion))
      return res;
    })
  )
}
```

Idem when you get an unique proyect

```
getProject(id){
  return this.httClient.get(....).pipe(
    map((res:any)=>{
      res.fechaPresentacion=new Date(res.fechaPresentacion))
      return res;
    })
  )
}
```

So, your components receive the property "fechaPresentacion" as a Date object

NOTE: the conversion to Date object works because the string is in format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here

```
this.columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'idPresentada', 'descripcion', 'fechaPresentacion', 'responsable', 'plazo', 'importe', 'organismo'];
```

I had 'fechapresentacion' and that is not matched with

[image]

Now I see all right

[image]